# Derive algebraic solution for $x^{\log_3 2} = \sqrt x + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I want algebraic solution to $$x^{\log_3 2} = \sqrt x + 1.$$ Computer solution says $x = 9$, but I've failed in several attempts to derive this answer algebraically. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't expect equations of this sort to have pleasant closed form solutions.  Here, one can guess the answer or, slightly more rigorously, solve it numerically and then deduce the exact result from the approximation.

Comment: I note, for example, the [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E%28log_3%282%29%29%3Dsqrt%28x%29%2B1) gives the answer as $x\approx 9$ and not $x=9$. This suggests that it too just follows a numerical method.

Comment: @lulu By algebraic solution I mean using laws of logarithm and index to get the answer. Also, what do you mean by numerical solution?

Comment: I understand what you want, I just don't think you'll get it.  Numerical methods might include graphical solutions or, better, things like [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  But in a case like this, I expect whoever set the problem expected you to guess that the answer was a power of $3$ (to make the left hand easy to compute).

Comment: @ lulu yes Wolfram Alpha gives $ x \approx 9$ but $x = 9$ is also a solution

Comment: I honestly can't imagine there's anything better here than guess-and-check, or using approximations to find a solution and extrapolating where they go (i.e. if your algorithm returns something very close to $9$, try $x=9$). For example, for the problem here: that you have $x$ to a power of $\log_3$ of something indicates you should try using powers of $3$ (if you hope your solution is a nice integer). The square root indicates you should try even exponents, so try $x=3^{2k}$ for nonnegative integers $k$. From there you reasonably quickly obtain a result, but that's just guessing and checking.

Comment: So yeah it's not an algebraic approach and assumes your solution is "nice,"  but unless you want to get into a lot  of higher level stuff you don't have much else.

Comment: If you use, as  Eevee Trainer commented $x=3^{2k}$, the equation becomes $4^k=3^k+1$ and $k=1$ is the root of it. Then, $x=9$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$a^{\log_b c}=c^{\log_b a}$$

Sothe equation becomes $$2^{\log_3 x}=\sqrt{x}+1$$
You may only verify that $x=9$ is a roots as
$$2^{\log_3 9}=2^2=4$$ and $$4=\sqrt{9}+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Below is an algebraic derivation. Reexpress both sides of the equation,

$$x^{\log_3 2} = \sqrt x + 1$$

as

$$RHS = \sqrt x + 1 = 3^{\log_3 \sqrt x} + 1 = 3^{\frac 12 \log_3 x}+ 1^{\frac 12 \log_3 x}$$

$$LHS = x^{\log_3 2} = (3^{log_3 x})^{\log_3 2}=(3^{log_3 2})^{\log_3 x}=2^{\log_3 x} =4^{\frac 12 \log_3 x}$$

As a result, the original equation can be expressed in a form of identical exponents,

$$4^{\frac 12 \log_3 x} = 3^{\frac 12 \log_3 x}+ 1^{\frac 12 \log_3 x}$$

Since $4=3+1$, the exponent must be one, i.e.

$$\frac 12 \log_3 x=1$$

which leads to the solution,

$$x=9$$